# How to fetch OpenShift project and quota info

Tags: openshift

Can we fetch a project (from namespace) and quota information with a single command by `oc`?

Like:

```
oc get project/quota --all-namespaces -o template --template="\
```

Comment: Look at description on getting details on quota in mailing list discussion at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/openshift/3XL0xh1Czj8/BEL3eZbuBgAJ

Answer (score 0):

Late I know, but maybe useful to someone:

```
oc get projects | awk '!/(NAME|other|exclusions)/ {print "echo "$1"; oc -n "$1" get quota -o yaml"}' | source /dev/stdin
```

Break down of the pipeline:

- list the projects

  ```
  oc get projects
  ```
- awk can match a regular expression pattern before it processes the line further. Here we exclude the header "NAME" and possibly projects that we don't want to be listed/processed. The $1 means the first column of input, so project name in this case. As awk output, we produce a command line:

  ```
   awk '!/(NAME|other|exclusions)/ {print "echo "$1"; oc -n "$1" get quota -o yaml"}'
  ```
- finally we pipe it into standard input, just as we'd typed it in.

  ```
  source /dev/stdin
  ```

Obviously, in the second step you can apply any formatting, templates etc.